# Why do I have 'replacement has length zero' error when looping through API calls?

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm a novice to programming and I'm trying to loop through a dataframe of addresses and call a google geocode API for each address to find the lat and long if I don't already have them. I have the API working correctly if you test it outside of the for loop, but when my loop hits a row with NAs in both the lat and long columns, i get the error `Error in stores$lat[i] <- geo$geometry.location.lat : replacement has length zero`.

The dataframe with the stores has a schema `stores <- data_frame(address,lat,long,call)`, where call is the specific API call for that address, e.g. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ICA+Supermarket+Övertorneå+Hemvägen+13+95731&key=****keyhidden****`

Code for the loop is below

```
for (i in 1:nrow(stores)) { # for every row
  if (is.na(stores$lat[i]) || is.na(stores$long[i])){ # if lat or long is empty
    get_geo <- GET(stores$call[i]) # call the relevant api call for that row
    class(get_geo)
    get_geo_text <- content(get_geo, as='text', encoding="UTF-8") 
    get_geo_json <- fromJSON(get_geo_text, flatten = TRUE) 
    geo <- data.frame(get_geo_json$results) 
    stores$lat[i] <- geo$geometry.location.lat 
    stores$long[i] <- geo$geometry.location.lng 
    Sys.sleep(time=1) # pause before next loop
  } 
}
```

Given my experience I expect the structure of my code isn't great, and comments on that would be welcome too, but my main concern is getting this thing to output as I need it to.

Thanks

Comment: `replacement has length zero` means you are trying to assign a value of length zero..check the api response and geo dataframe has the expected data before assign to the store dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replacement has length zero` means you are trying to assign a value of length zero..check the api response and geo dataframe has the expected data before assign to the store dataframe.you should try to assign store lat and long only if geo dataframe has the relevent data.

```
geo <- data.frame(get_geo_json$results)
if(nrow(geo)>0){ 
  stores$lat[i] <- geo$geometry.location.lat 
  stores$long[i] <- geo$geometry.location.lng 
}
```

Comment: thanks - i think this did the trick. the errors were being thrown when no address was being found by the API